# Problems with CSS positioning - there's unused space

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I finally managed to make my z-indexes working.

I used the following CSS:

```
.front {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #2a2a2a;
  top: -430px;     
  z-index: 2000;
}

.rotate {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  left: 40px;
  width: 580px;
  height: 580px;
  -webkit-animation:spin 60s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 60s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 60s linear infinite;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<img src="sunburst.png" width="580" class="rotate"/>
<img src="sfsfs.png" width="340" height="227" class="front" />
```

The problem is, that there is a lot of empty space below these which I did not manage to make disappear. The images are in a table cell and this is the layout:

[image]

The orange and blue squares are the images. The dotted space is not used and I'd like to delete it.

For those of you who wonder, this is the thing I'd like to do:

[image]

(Which is now kind of working.)

The back image is also rotating, this is why I couldn't do this with a simple "background". (or.. could I?)

How can I make the unused space disappear? And also, if you have any better ideas on how to do this, please feel free to educate me.

Comment: You are using `top: -430px; `..this can leave blank space (on `relative`)

Answer (score 0):

float your div 2 to the right not left.

And write your css properly, not as style in the div

http://jsfiddle.net/feqJT/1

```
.b {
    float : right;
    width : 90px;
    height : 90px;
}
```

You can then get rid of space by changing the size of the holding div, or add padding-right:20px; or margin-right:20px; depending what you want. Difference between padding and margin for a different post.

```
.b{float : right; width : 90px; height : 90px; margin-right:20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with css background. The only thing you need is to have an animated gif which shows the animation:

```
<div class="bg">
    <img src="http://www.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/blueprint/placeholders/gif/extras/icons/256x256.gif" class="placeholder"></img>
</div>
```

and your css will look like this:

```
.bg{
    background-image: url(http://media.giphy.com/media/YXrVp9LULJ80o/giphy.gif);
    width:320px;
    height:400px;
}
.placeholder{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:75px;
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/okca6mjj/

Answer (score 0):

The problem got fixed by adding a negative bottom margin. So silly I did not think of this. :)